# On Group Near-Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I still not understand clearly about group near-ring. Definition of group near-ring given here:

[image: taken from the book "S - near-ring]

1. multiplication in G implies usual multiplication or it can be any defined multiplication?
2. does G not necessarily finite since group near-ring NG consist of all finite formal sums?
3. why it must be satisfied the four condition?
4. this question related to 3rd question, from $\alpha_1g_1(\beta_1h_1+...+\beta_mh_m)$ to $\alpha_1(\beta_1g_1h_1+...+\beta_mg_1h_m)$, why is it possible even the Group G and near-ring N not always commutative? it should be $\alpha_1(g_1\beta_1h_1+...+g_1\beta_mh_m)$, right?
5. what is the operation of group near-ring NG since it called group? it depends on the group G and near-ring N?
6. Below the word "This will be defined in this text in two ways:", number one should be, $\sum \alpha_1g_1 \sum \beta_jh_j = \sum \alpha_ig_i$ instead of $\sum \alpha_1g_1 \sum \beta_jh_j = \sum \alpha_1g_i$, right?

Thank You so much, forgive me if it's too many question in a single ask.

Comment: I think you should also add the definition of near ring and/or near field...

Comment: near-ring is a ring which is the group addition is not necessarily abelian, also satisfied only one  distiributive law, while near field, is a commutative near-ring with identity element 1

Comment: A ring always has abelian addition. To make the addition non-abelian you need to break more of the ring axioms (it seems here that they are not assuming distributivity to hold for all elements). Anyway, from your questions it seems that you really ought to read up on these things in the classical setting of group algebras over a field first, as most of your questions are not really related to the setting of a near-ring, and you really need to understand the classical setting first.

Comment: what you mean by classical setting?

Comment: I mean the case of group algebras over a field (or just group rings). Most of your questions suggest that you are not familiar with this, and you really need to be to understand what happens for near-rings.

Comment: ah, maybe. imho, im familiar with group, but not group rings, so i guess i'll read it up now. any reference about group ring? And, if you know, everything or some answer of my question, why not you write it down here? while im also reading my gap, it will be really appreciated and surely help me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Group rings will be covered by pretty much any introductory text on representations of groups (at least over a field).

Comment: ah, thank myou, i'll looking in dummit fotre first. I'm still waiting your answer to some of my question :), help me okey..